# ¿Como realizar un registro en mi base de datos?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo una funcion en JS para registrar un texto en una base de datos pero no funciona mi codigo, lo que quiero hacer es que al dar click en el boton verifique si en campo "Input" esta vacio en caso de estarlo muestra en consola "Ingresa codigo" <-- Esto funciona y no tengo ningun problema, el problema viene cuando quiero realizar un POST con ajax pero me da un error de sintaxis y no lo puedo encontrar.

```
function uploadTxt(){
            let input_txt;

            input_txt = document.getElementById('txt_notificacion').value;

            if (input_txt.length == 0){
                console.log("Ingresa el texto");
            }else{

                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url:"registro_txt.php",
                        data:{
                            txt : $("#txt_notificacion").val(),}
                        success:function(r){
                            if(r==1){
                                console.log("Registrado correctamente");
                            }else{
                                console.log("No Se Ha Registrado correctamente");
                            }
                        }
                    });                    
                });                                 

            }                 
        }
```

En mi registro PHP tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?php

require_once "db.php";
$conn = conexion();

    $Texto=$_POST['txt'];

$sql="INSERT into txt_parrafo (Texto)
    values ('Texto')";

echo $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

?>

Espero me puedan ayudar. :)

Answer (score 0):

El error lo tenes en esta linea de codigo
 txt : $("#txt_notificacion").val(),}
seria 
 txt : $("#txt_notificacion").val()},
La coma va después del cierre de llave